# Visual Studio Code does not implement IntelliSense correctly for numpy but works for all other modules [Pictures inside]

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I started working in Visual Studio Code and configured python IntelliSense. Untill now everything is working like a charm. However, IntelliSense works perfectly with all packages except numpy objects. The pictures below explains the problem better. One shows numpy object and the other shows request object.

I tried to reinstall numpy and enabling jedi but nothing changed.

[image][image]

Comment: You did set the interpreter to the one in the virtual environment where you installed `numpy`?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Yes I did

Comment: Are you using Jedi?